# Definition vs initialization

Tags: javascript, initialization, declaration, definition

What's the difference between declaration, definition and initialization? Example:

```
// Is this a declaration?
var foo;

// Did I defined object in here (but it is empty)?
var foo = {};

// Now that object is initialized with some value?
var foo = {first:"number_one"};
```

Comment: It would help if you tagged the question with the language you are using

Answer (score 5):

The first example is a declaration. You have declared a variable with the identifier `foo`. You haven't given it a value yet, so it will be `undefined`:

```
var foo;
console.log(foo); //undefined
```

The second example is a declaration and an assignment. You have assigned an empty object literal to the variable with the identifier `foo`. As noted in the comments, this is effectively short for:

```
var foo;
console.log(foo); //undefined
foo = {};
console.log(foo); //Object
```

The third example is another declaration and another assignment. You have assigned a different object literal to `foo`.

**Edit** (see comments)

The behaviour of your code is slightly different depending on whether you intended each example to run as an independent program, or as written (one program).

*If you treat is as it's written:*

Because variable declarations in JavaScript are hoisted to the top of the scope in which they appear, redeclaring variables has no effect. So the first line declares a variable `foo`.

The second line assigns an empty object literal to `foo`, and the third line assigns a different object literal to `foo`. Both of these assignments apply to the same `foo`.

What effectively happens is this:

```
var foo;
foo = {}; //No `var` keyword
foo = {first:"number_one"}; //No `var` keyword
```

*If you treat each line as a separate program:*

The first program declares a variable named `foo`. It's value is `undefined`.

The second program declares a variable named `foo`, and then assigns an empty object literal to it.

The third program declares a variable named `foo` and then assigns an object literal with one property to it.

Comment: The last two are also declarations. `var a = b;` is shorthand for `var a; a = b;`.

Comment: @pimvdb - Very true, I didn't notice the use of `var` in 2nd and 3rd examples (I assumed the first example was declaring `foo`, and the same `foo` was being reused in the other examples).

Comment: @pimvdb - Actually, is it not just an assignment? Redeclaring `foo` won't have any effect (since declarations are hoisted), so any "declarations" of `foo` following the initial declaration won't really be declarations, but rather just assignments. Unless of course you take all 3 examples as separate programs.

Comment: Touche. If the statements are all run in one function, then the last two `var`s have no effect.

Answer (score 2):

You got it right.

```
var foo;        // Is this a declaration ?
```

Yes, you declared that there's a variable named `foo`, but didn't define `foo` (so `foo` is undefined).

```
var foo = {}    // Did I defined object in here (but it is empty) ?
```

Yes, now you "defined" `foo`... it has a value, it is no longer undefined. `var foo = 5` also counts as "defining" it.

```
var foo = {first:"number_one"}  // Now that object is initialized with some value ?
```

You could say that it's "initialized," but that's really just semantics. "Declared" and "defined" are a bit more meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

Run the code below:

```
var foo;
console.dir(foo);
var foo = {};
console.dir(foo);
var foo = {first:"number_one"};
console.dir(foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a variable with `var foo;` you actually ensure that it will belong to the scope where you've defined it. What you call definition and initialization is in fact a value assignment.

Consider following piece of code as an example:

```
(function () {

  // definition
  var foo;

  function assignFoo(x) {
    // assignment
    foo = x;
  }

  assignFoo(5);

  console.log(foo);

})();
```

To say, you're not always supposed to assign value within the scope of definition. But it is the most common use case which is usually accomplished with `var foo = 5`.

Thats it.